# Audio multi-cast software needs a multi-window `Click down` .. was this tested?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to multi-cast audio do a number of channels.  The software requires that I click and hold a button to broadcast.  So, I wrote this little script to do the job.

After running several copies of the software, the loop is supposto cycle through the windows and click and hold all of the broadcast buttons.  However, only the first button sticks but the other buttons do not appear to click or hold.

The encouraging thing is, I can run the script and as the first button is being held (by the script's action), I can manually click and hold down a second button in another window.  The programs work as intended sending voice down all channels.  Perhaps there is an issue in the auto-hot-key program.

Here is the code:

```
#enter::
Loop 3 {
  SetTitleMatchMode, Slow
  IfWinExist, Virtual Base Station, USER_%a_index%  
  {
    WinActivate
    WinWaitActive  
    Click down 400,60
  }
}
```

Update: I have a work around.  The multi-cast program allows the space key as a short cut too.  Send {Space down} does function on multiple windows.  All windows think the space bar is being held down.

Comment: When you use AHK Windows Spy, and you hover over the buttons, can you see if these buttons have a unique ClassNN: ID?  If so, you might be able to use controlSend {Click Down} or {Enter Down} to each element.

Comment: That is a better way to identify the button, thanks.  It works the same.  Also, the button does not respond to Enter down, only Click down.

Comment: Not the topic, but sounds like a bad piece of software to me. Are you sure, you can't trigger a continuous broadcast without having to keep pressing a button? Maybe something hidden under preferences? If not, I have to ask: What's the purpose of such a seemingly preposterous imperative, imposed by this program?

Comment: Currently the script you have would find the first "Virtual Base Station" window and activate that three times. Have a look at this example [link](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/54584-how-to-complie-a-list-of-all-window-names/) on how to find the different windows so you can activate each of them.

Comment: The loop is working.  I see each window come to the foreground.  Also, I have used this loop to open any windows that do not exists.  Thanks for the tip, that syntax looks better; I'll test it.